# How to rotate the ticklabel_format in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot a figure and I want to rotate the direction of `zaxis.set_major_formatter`. As shown in the image with the red mark.  How could I rotate it?

```
Fontsize_set = {'size' : 20}
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8, 5], dpi = 140, facecolor = None)
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.grid(color = 'y', linestyle = ':', linewidth = 0.5)

## axes tick setting.
ax.tick_params(labelsize = 20)
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1500)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 1500, 1500 / 5))
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 250)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 250, 250 / 5))
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 0.025)
ax.set_zticks(np.arange(0, 0.025, 0.025 / 5))

ax.view_init(20, 60)

ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)     ## rotate the z axis.
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter(useMathText = True))
ax.ticklabel_format(style = "sci",  axis = "z", scilimits = (-3, -3))

ax.xaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.yaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.zaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.xaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.yaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.zaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.xaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.yaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.zaxis.pane.fill = False

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The image as shown in below:

[image]

```
Fontsize_set = {'size' : 20}
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8, 5], dpi = 140, facecolor = 'w')
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.grid(color = 'y', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)
## axes tick setting.
ax.tick_params(labelsize = 20)

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 2000)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 2000, 2000 / 5))

ax.set_ylim3d(0, 250)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 250, 250 / 5))

ax.set_zlim3d(0, 0.0025)
ax.set_zticks(np.arange(0, 0.0025, 0.0025 / 5))

ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter(useMathText = True))
ax.ticklabel_format(style = "sci", axis = "z", scilimits = (-4, -4))

ax.view_init(20, 60)
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)     ## rotate the z label.

fig.canvas.draw()
ax.zaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
ax.text2D(0.05, 0.85, ax.zaxis.offsetText.get_text(),
          transform = ax.transAxes, fontsize = 10)
ax.xaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.yaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.zaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.xaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.yaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.zaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.xaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.yaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.zaxis.pane.fill = False
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
Fontsize_set = {'size' : 20}
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8, 5], dpi = 140, facecolor = 'w')
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.grid(color = 'y', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)
## axes tick setting.
ax.tick_params(labelsize = 20)

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 2000)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 2000, 2000 / 5))

ax.set_ylim3d(0, 250)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 250, 250 / 5))

ax.set_zlim3d(0, 0.0025)
ax.set_zticks(np.arange(0, 0.0025, 0.0025 / 5))

ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter(useMathText = True))
ax.ticklabel_format(style = "sci", axis = "z", scilimits = (-4, -4))

ax.view_init(20, 60)
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)     ## rotate the z label.

ax.zaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
ax.text2D(0.05, 0.85, r'$\times$$10^{-3}$',
          transform = ax.transAxes, fontsize = 20)
ax.xaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.yaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.zaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.xaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.yaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.zaxis.pane.set_alpha(1)
ax.xaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.yaxis.pane.fill = False
ax.zaxis.pane.fill = False
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting with tab completions and `matplotlib` documentation, I could only come up with the following alternative. The idea is simple:

- Hide the exponent term which is the `offsetText`.
- Replace it with a simple text in horizontal layout.

The position of the text `0.05, 0.85,` is a matter of choice. Please note that on my system, I get an exponent of -2 whereas you got -3. But it doesn't matter as the z-ticklabels are accordingly rescaled.

```
fig.canvas.draw()
ax.zaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
ax.text2D(0.05, 0.85, ax.zaxis.offsetText.get_text(), 
          transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments.  I added your code in my program, but it plots without exponent.  That means 'offsetText' function goes well, but the text does not work.

Comment: @wentonglu: You mean `ax.text2D(....)` command does not work for you? I am just using the code you provided in the question and it works for me. What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: @wentonglu: Can you try commenting out `plt.tight_layout()` and then check?

Comment: Yes, I mean 'ax.text2D(....)' command does not work for me.  In addition, I am using version of 3.0.3 matplotlib.  The 'plt.tight_layout()' also had been commented out and then nothing changed.

Comment: @wentonglu: Ok, try the normal `ax.text` as `ax.text(1550, -50, 0.025, ax.zaxis.offsetText.get_text(), fontsize=20)`

Comment: I think the problem is that the command 'ax.zaxis.offsetText.get_text()' does not work.  Because I use 'none character words' instead.  It works.

Comment: What did you do to make it work? I did not understand your comment

Comment: The code and image have been updated, please check it.

Comment: @wentonglu: Replace `'$\times $ $10^{-3}$'` by `r'$\times $ $10^{-3}$'` and  try again and let me know

Comment: I have already done it.  I will update the image, please check it.  Think you for your kind comments.

Comment: r'$\times$$10^{-3}$' font is strange, even I used the font set as 'bold'.  The fontwight shows normal style.  Would you please tell me what should I do?  Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will read the 'What should I do when someone answers my question?' and upvote now.

Comment: The thing is that you cannot write exponents (^, powers) without LaTeX mode.

Comment: Okay, I see.  Thank you very much.  You are so kind and very patient.  ^ - ^